# Python: Longest Plateau Problem: to find the length and location of the longest contiguous sequence of equal values

Tags: python, algorithm

The question is to solve the following question in Sedgewick Wayne's Python book:

Given an array of integers, compose a program that finds the length and location of the longest contiguous sequence of equal values where the values of the elements just before and just after this sequence are smaller.

I tried on this problem, and encountered some problems.

Here are my codes:

```
import sys
import stdio

# Ask the user input for the list of integers
numList = list(sys.argv[1])

maxcount = 0
value = None
location = None

i = 1
while i < len(numList) - 1:
    resList = []
    count = 0
    # If i > i-1, then we start taking i into the resList
    if numList[i] > numList[i - 1]:
        # start counting
        resList += [numList[i]]
        # Iterating through the rest of the numbers
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(numList):
            # If the j element equals the i, then append it to resList
            if numList[i] == numList[j]:
                resList += [numList[j]]
                j += 1
            elif numList[i] < numList[j]:
                # if j element is greater than i, break out the loop
                i = j
                break
            else:
                # if j element is smaller than i, count equals length of resList
                count = len(resList)
                if count > maxcount:
                    maxcount = count
                    value = resList[1]
                    location = i
                i = j
    else:
        # if not greater than the previous one, increment by 1
        i += 1

stdio.writeln("The longest continuous plateau is at location: " + str(location))
stdio.writeln("Length is: " + str(maxcount))
stdio.writeln("Number is: " + str(value))
```

The result shows:

```
python exercise1_4_21.py 553223334445554
The longest continuous plateau is at location: 11
Length is: 3
Number is: 5


python exercise1_4_21.py 1234567
The longest continuous plateau is at location: None
Length is: 0
Number is: None
```

But somehow, if the list given is in the format of having a group of continuous integers that is greater than the previous one, but then this group ends the list with no integer following it, my program simply doesn't end....

```
exercise1_4_21.py 11112222111444
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exercise1_4_21.py", line 32, in <module>
    if numList[i] == numList[j]:
KeyboardInterrupt


exercise1_4_21.py 111222211112223333
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exercise1_4_21.py", line 25, in <module>
    if numList[i] > numList[i - 1]:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Not quite sure where the logical error is...thank you very much for your help and kindness!

Comment: You didn't account for the case when your inner loop exits because `j` becomes equal to `len(numList)`. `i` doesn't get updated in this case, so the outer loop runs indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you overcomplicated the solution (while correctly selected key cases).

It requires only single run through the list.

```
def maxplat(l):
    if (len(l)==0):
        return 0, 0
    start, leng = 0, 1
    maxlen, maxstart = 0, 1
    for i in range(1, len(l) + 1):
        if (i == len(l)) or (l[i] < l[i-1]):
            if (leng > maxlen):
                maxlen, maxstart = leng, start
        elif (l[i] == l[i-1]):
            leng += 1
        else:
            start, leng = i, 1
    return maxlen, maxstart

#test cases
print(maxplat([]))  #empty case
print(maxplat([3]))  #single element
print(maxplat([3,2,4,4,2,5,5,5,3]))   #simple case
print(maxplat([3,2,4,4,2,5,5,5,6]))  #up after long run
print(maxplat([3,2,4,4,2,5,5,5]))    #run at the end
print(maxplat([3,3,3,3,2,4,4,2]))   #run at the start

>>> 
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
(3, 5)
(2, 2)
(3, 5)
(4, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra check in your code to exit.

```
if j == len(numList):
   maxcount = len(resList)
   value = resList[1]
   location = i
   break
```

In your code it'll look like this:

```
import sys
import stdio

# Ask the user input for the list of integers
numList = list(sys.argv[1])

maxcount = 0
value = None
location = None

i = 1
while i < len(numList) - 1:
    resList = []
    count = 0
    # If i > i-1, then we start taking i into the resList
    if numList[i] > numList[i - 1]:
        # start counting
        resList += [numList[i]]
        # Iterating through the rest of the numbers
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(numList):
            # If the j element equals the i, then append it to resList
            if numList[i] == numList[j]:
                resList += [numList[j]]
                j += 1
            elif numList[i] < numList[j]:
                # if j element is greater than i, break out the loop
                i = j
                break
            else:
                # if j element is smaller than i, count equals length of resList
                count = len(resList)
                if count > maxcount:
                    maxcount = count
                    value = resList[1]
                    location = i
                i = j
        #EXTRA CHECK HERE
        if j == len(numList):
            maxcount = len(resList)
            value = resList[1]
            location = i
            break
    else:
        # if not greater than the previous one, increment by 1
        i += 1

stdio.writeln("The longest continuous plateau is at location: " + str(location))
stdio.writeln("Length is: " + str(maxcount))
stdio.writeln("Number is: " + str(value))
```

Comment: When j == len(numList), just break out of the loop. If you update maxcount at the #Extra check here, since you didn't check whether the last item in the given list is smaller than the item in the current longest list, it could be wrong. If you run 12333334555543444444355555, it gives 55555 as the answer.